# Phalcon ORM isNew

Tags: phalcon

Does Phalcon's ORM have something like `isNew`?

Currently I'm use:

```
{% if user.getID() %}
    {{ 'Edit user ' ~ user.name }}
{% else %}
    {{ 'New user' }}
{% endif %}
```

but not sure if this is the right way.

Phalcon 1.3.x please.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this type of pattern on all my models and use isNew() in the same way you do.

```
class SomeModel extends Phalcon\Mvc\Collection {

    public static function getNew() {

        $t = new self();
        $t->someFieldToInit = 'some-val';
        return $t;
    }

    public static function findByIdOrNew($_id) {

        $t = self::findById($_id);
        return $t ?: self::getNew();
    }

    public function isNew() {

        return !$this->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method *getId* seems not available in the last version : https://docs.phalconphp.com/3.4/en/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model

It could use the "dirty state" instead :

```
public function isNew() {
    return $this->getDirtyState() == self::DIRTY_STATE_TRANSIENT;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What isNew mean in your situation? If it checked anyone has just register into your site. Maybe we could use authentication to get that User

Comment: Interests me the possibility of creating ONE form (e.g. VOLT view) for creating and editing models. For example using in 
**backend/views/users/edit.volt** and **backend/views/users/new.volt** `{% include 'users/_form' with ['form':form, 'user':user] %}`